# switch between alias definitions

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, alias

I'm trying to use `alias` command to switch between two definitions (trying to use Rust's `cargo` and Crystal's compiler `crystal` from command line). I have the following in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
   alias c=crystal
   alias cargo="unalias c; alias c=cargo"
   alias crystal="unalias c; alias c=crystal"
```

However, when I try to run something like

> > c macro.rs

in macOS terminal I get

> bash: alias: macro.rs: not found

What may be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what's happening here:

```
$ set -x
$ c file
+ unalias c
+ alias c=crystal file
bash: alias: file: not found
$ set +x
```

So, `c file` is expanded to `unalias c; alias c=crystal file` (via an intermediate expansion to `crystal file`).

`alias c=crystal file` doesn't make sense.  What I think you might have wanted is for `crystal file` to be executed.

You might want to rename the aliases that switches the meanings of `c`:

```
alias usecrystal="alias c=crystal"
alias usecargo="alias c=cargo"
```

Alternatively, you may protect the command from alias expansion:

```
alias c="\crystal"
alias crystal="alias c=\crystal"
alias cargo="alias c=\cargo"
```

Or use `command` (which IMHO looks better):

```
alias c="command crystal"
alias crystal='alias c="command crystal"'
alias cargo='alias c="command cargo"'
```

The `command` command also protects from alias expansion.